# Matplotlib shrinking Value of "Price"

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have created a DataFrame from `car_data`:

```py
import pandas as pd

class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, year, price, mileage, color, buy_rate):
        self.make = make
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.color = color
        self.buy_rate = buy_rate


cars_data = [
    {"make": "Toyota", "year": 2018, "price": 20000, "mileage": 50000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Honda", "year": 2019, "price": 25000, "mileage": 40000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Ford", "year": 2020, "price": 28000, "mileage": 30000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.6},
    {"make": "Chevrolet", "year": 2017, "price": 18000, "mileage": 60000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Nissan", "year": 2019, "price": 23000, "mileage": 35000, "color": "Silver", "buy_rate": 0.65},
    {"make": "BMW", "year": 2021, "price": 35000, "mileage": 20000, "color": "Gray", "buy_rate": 0.55},
    {"make": "Mercedes", "year": 2018, "price": 30000, "mileage": 45000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Audi", "year": 2020, "price": 32000, "mileage": 25000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Subaru", "year": 2019, "price": 22000, "mileage": 35000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Hyundai", "year": 2020, "price": 26000, "mileage": 30000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.65},
    {"make": "Kia", "year": 2017, "price": 20000, "mileage": 55000, "color": "Green", "buy_rate": 0.6},
    {"make": "Volkswagen", "year": 2018, "price": 24000, "mileage": 40000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Tesla", "year": 2022, "price": 60000, "mileage": 15000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.85},
    {"make": "Lexus", "year": 2019, "price": 35000, "mileage": 25000, "color": "Silver", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Mazda", "year": 2018, "price": 21000, "mileage": 45000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Jeep", "year": 2020, "price": 29000, "mileage": 20000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.65},
    {"make": "Volvo", "year": 2021, "price": 38000, "mileage": 30000, "color": "Gray", "buy_rate": 0.6},
    {"make": "Chrysler", "year": 2019, "price": 27000, "mileage": 35000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Buick", "year": 2017, "price": 22000, "mileage": 40000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Ferrari", "year": 2022, "price": 150000, "mileage": 10000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.9},
    {"make": "Acura", "year": 2020, "price": 33000, "mileage": 22000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Porsche", "year": 2021, "price": 45000, "mileage": 18000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.85},
    {"make": "Infiniti", "year": 2018, "price": 32000, "mileage": 28000, "color": "Gray", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Land Rover", "year": 2019, "price": 55000, "mileage": 25000, "color": "Green", "buy_rate": 0.65},
    {"make": "Jaguar", "year": 2020, "price": 60000, "mileage": 20000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.6},
    {"make": "Maserati", "year": 2021, "price": 70000, "mileage": 15000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Bentley", "year": 2019, "price": 80000, "mileage": 12000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Rolls Royce", "year": 2020, "price": 100000, "mileage": 10000, "color": "Silver", "buy_rate": 0.9},
    {"make": "Lincoln", "year": 2018, "price": 45000, "mileage": 20000, "color": "Black", "buy_rate": 0.8},
    {"make": "Cadillac", "year": 2017, "price": 40000, "mileage": 30000, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.75},
    {"make": "Aston Martin", "year": 2021, "price": 150000, "mileage": 8000, "color": "Red", "buy_rate": 0.85},
    {"make": "Alfa Romeo", "year": 2019, "price": 60000, "mileage": 20000, "color": "White", "buy_rate": 0.7},
    {"make": "Bugatti", "year": 2020, "price": 3000000, "mileage": 500, "color": "Blue", "buy_rate": 0.95},
]


cars = []
for car_data in cars_data:
    car = Car(car_data["make"], car_data["year"], car_data["price"], car_data["mileage"], car_data["color"], car_data["buy_rate"])
    cars.append(car)

car_data_dict = {
    "Make": [car.make for car in cars],
    "Year": [car.year for car in cars],
    "Price": [car.price for car in cars],
    "Mileage": [car.mileage for car in cars],
    "Color": [car.color for car in cars],
    "Buy Rate": [car.buy_rate for car in cars]
}

car_df = pd.DataFrame(car_data_dict)
print(car_df)
```

Then I created a plot from the DF like this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))

scatter = ax.scatter(x=car_df['Price'],
                     y=car_df['Year'],
                     c=car_df['Year'])

ax.set(title="Car data >=2024 ",
       xlabel='Price',
       ylabel='Year')
```

and the output:

[image: Matplotlib plot]

Why doesn't it show thousands for price? When I print out this line:

```
car_df['Price'][0]
```

It returns `20000` as expected.

*Note: This didn't happen before I added Mileage.*

Comment: What is the question exactly? Since we don't have a [mre] it is hard to tell if anything is wrong in this graph. If see that you have 20000 in the example you show. Which is also plotted on the graph. What were you expecting exactly, and why do you think `car_df['Price'][0]` being 20000 should show a contraction?

Comment: The Price in the scatter plot are numbers 0-3 while mine were supposed to be thousands, as in the car_data dict + car_df. My question is why, and can it be somehow "fixed"?

Comment: No, the price in the scatter plot are number 0-3 MILLIONS. Look closely the axis.

Comment: OOOH. . . I think I understand now. @chrslg do you want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the price in the scatter plot are number 0-3 MILLIONS. Look closely the axis.

If you want to avoid that you can add

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

[image]

Or you can set your own formatter

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%4.1g"))
```

[image]